# Pass a parameter in a return array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

i need to return this.

```
GetBooking = function (parameter) {
    return Booking.Title[0].parameter;
 }

GetPages = function () {
    return GetBooking(pages) 
 }

GetNumber = function () {
    return GetBooking(number) 
 }
```

booking is a object of arrays, is possible?

Comment: This is an... odd paradigm, and a more odd naming scheme. I would re-consider this design entirely, otherwise you're arbitrarily making things very hard for yourself and future maintainers of this code.

Comment: It's a bit unclear. But, you probably need [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) instead of [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Dot_notation) here: `Booking.Title[0][parameter]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, when doing `GetBooking(pages)` you expect to get in return `Booking.Title[0].pages`, meaning `GetBooking()` function is supposed to be like a middleman to decide which property you want to get from `Booking.Title[0]`.

If I'm correct, then you almost had it right. What will happen in your code is, for example if `number` was 7, it would look for a property named `7` inside `Booking.Title[0]`.

What you really want to do is this: `return Booking.Title[0][parameter]`, and `parameter` has to be a string value representing the property you're looking for, meaning you also need to change the rest of the code which would ultimately look like this:

```
GetBooking = function (parameter) {
    return Booking.Title[0][parameter];
 }

GetPages = function () {
    return GetBooking("pages") ;
 }

GetNumber = function () {
    return GetBooking("number") ;
 }
```

This will take the string in `parameter` and look for a property that matches that string inside `Booking.Title[0]`, and return its value.